# Install only one package from package.json?

Tags: npm

Suppose that somewhere in my `package.json` I have:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bower": "1.0.0",
    // zillion other dependencies
}
```

Is there a way to make npm install **only** bower@1.0.0 from my `package.json`? Like so: `npm install --only bower`.

My goal is to make `npm install` and `bower install` run simultaneously.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As a workaround you may use something like:

```
$ node -pe "require('./package').dependencies.bower"
// → 1.0.0
$ npm install bower@$(node -pe "require('./package').dependencies.bower")
// npm install bower@1.0.0

// or with jq
$ npm install bower@$(< package.json jq -r '.dependencies.bower')
```

Where `-e/--eval` flag evaluates passed string and `-p/--print` prints result of eval.

---

Please consider other answers as well since this one may be outdated.

Comment: If there is `npm-shrinkwrap.json` then `npm install bower` will respect versions from it.

Comment: JIC, this may install the package on different minor or patch version, if you are using `^` or `~`. So, if you have a `package-lock.json`, you can do: `node -p -e "require('./package-lock.json').dependencies.bower.version"`

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work anymore with at least npm version 6.12.1

Answer (score 17):

As @atalantus noted in comment, the accepted answer doesn't work on newer version of NPM. Working solution for newer versions (verified on NPM 6.13.4) is:

```
npm install --no-package-lock --no-save bower@1.0.0
```

This will install `bower` and all its dependencies, but prevents installation of anything else you might have in `package.json`. It also doesn't create or modify existing `package-lock.json`.

From npm documentation:

> The `--no-package-lock` argument will prevent npm from creating a package-lock.json file. When running with package-lock's disabled npm will not automatically prune your node modules when installing.

> `--no-save`: Prevents saving to `dependencies`.

Combining this with Anton Rudeshko's approach to find out version in `package.json`, the final solution is:

```
VERSION_BOWER=`node -p -e "require('./package.json').dependencies.bower"`
npm install --no-package-lock --no-save bower@"$VERSION_BOWER"
```

## Update 2023

Alternative solution I've just used is to temporarily modify `package.json` to only keep the dependency you need. That can be done quite easily with help of `jq`

Given package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "1.0.0",
    "foo": "^1.2.3",
    "bar": "^4.5.6",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "baz": "^10.20.30",
  }
}
```

Let's first modify it with `jq` to only keep `bower`

```
cat package.json| jq 'del(.devDependencies) | .dependencies |= {bower:.bower}'
```

Gives us

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

by deleting `devDependencies` completely and leaving only `bower` in `dependencies`.

Next up you would want to overwrite package.json with this new, version, but you can't do it directly like this

```
cat package.json | jq 'del(.devDependencies) | .dependencies |= {bower:.bower}' > package.json
```

because the file gets overwritten before it's fully read. Instead you need to buffer the output stream of `jq` command, simplest solution just storing it in variable, and then overwriting the original file

```
updated=`cat package.json | jq 'del(.devDependencies) | .dependencies |= {bower:.bower}'`
echo $updated > package.json
```

And `package.json` now reads:

```
cat package.json
{
  "name": "sample",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Run `npm install` now and you only install `bower@1.0.0`.

Obviously not always we can afford to modify the file, but you could also back-up the original file, etc. Main point is here how to easily modify json file thanks to `jq` rather than playing magic tricks with `sed` :-)

Comment: This no longer work as of NPM 7.8.0 ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3023)). Even if you delete `package-lock.json` and pass all the arguments you want, `npm install local-iso-dt --no-package-lock --production` will still install everything in `package.json` instead of only that zero-dependencies [local-iso-dt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-iso-dt) module.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as with newer versions of NPM the previous solutions don't work anymore, I came up with this:

```
npm i -g --prefix=$(pwd) bower # $(pwd) = current directory, UNIX only
node bin/bower
```

Installing a package globally allows you to specify a "prefix" - a directory where the package will be installed. Here I just put the current directory as the folder I want the package to appear in. In CI, this will probably be your repo root.

Keep in mind this will ignore your package.json version and just download the latest one. If you need a specific version, just use `bower@someversion` instead.

---

An alternative solution is just `rm package.json && npm i bower`, or `mv package.json _package.json && npm i bower` if you want to restore it later

Answer (score 1):

I see that the most upvoted solution doesn't work for latest node versions. Even tho it also provides an alternative solution updated for 2023, I'd rather work around with something simpler, such as:

```bash
mv package.json package.json.bkp
npm install --no-save bower@1.0.0
mv package.json.bkp package.json
```

Comment: this is a nice clean solution

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar requirement – I needed to create a task in a build system that would install a single package and execute its binary, not caring about the rest of the packages. Since this pops up as a first result in Google search, I’m sharing what I’ve learned here.

Because each task runs in isolation in the build system, I could basically do whatever I wanted to when it comes to deleting files. With this in mind, here’s what worked for me:

1. Make sure `node_modules` are not present. If they are, just delete them using `rm -rf node_modules`.
2. Delete `package.json` and `package-lock.json` using `rm package.json package-lock.json`
3. Install the required dependency: `npm install <package>`
4. Do whatever you need to do with it (in my case, I executed the package’s binary).

Steps 1 and 2 ensure that the created `package.json` in step 3 will have no dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following script to install only one dependency from package.json using pnpm

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Set the package name and dependency type from the command line arguments
PACKAGE_NAME=$1
DEPENDENCY_TYPE=$2

# Get the version of the package from the package.json file
PACKAGE_VERSION="$(node -p "require('./package.json').${DEPENDENCY_TYPE}['${PACKAGE_NAME}']")"

# Print the version for debugging purposes
echo "Installing ${PACKAGE_NAME}@${PACKAGE_VERSION} from ${DEPENDENCY_TYPE}"

# Rename package.json to _package.json
mv package.json _package.json

# Install the package using pnpm
pnpm add "${PACKAGE_NAME}@${PACKAGE_VERSION}"

# Rename _package.json back to package.json
mv _package.json package.json

echo "${PACKAGE_NAME}@${PACKAGE_VERSION} installed successfully from ${DEPENDENCY_TYPE}"
```

and run it like this:

```bash
./scripts/installOnePackage.sh bower dependencies
```