# `npm install` always installs everything from package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, continuous-integration

I'm trying to set up some CI tests that rely on a few Node modules, but don't require installing everything in package.json. I figured I could do this like so:

`npm install --no-save eslint stylelint stylelint-config-standard stylelint-order stylelint-scss`

Doing that, however, still installs everything from my `devDependencies` in package.json. How can I tell NPM to ignore my package.json, and only install what I'm specifically telling it to?

---

EDIT: To better demonstrate the problem I'm running in to, I deleted `node_modules` out of one of my projects, and attempted to run `npm install --no-save mkdirp`. mkdirp is a very simple module with one dependency, but as you can see from the output below, NPM went ahead and still installed everything in my `package.json`.

```
jacob@RYZEN:~/Repositories/new-site$ npm install --no-save mkdirp

> puppeteer@1.8.0 install /mnt/c/Users/Jacob/Repositories/new-site/node_modules/puppeteer
> node install.js

Downloading Chromium r588429 - 103.7 Mb [====================] 100% 0.0s
Chromium downloaded to /mnt/c/Users/Jacob/Repositories/new-site/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-588429

> node-sass@4.9.3 install /mnt/c/Users/Jacob/Repositories/new-site/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at /home/jacob/.npm/node-sass/4.9.3/linux-x64-57_binding.node

> gifsicle@3.0.4 postinstall /mnt/c/Users/Jacob/Repositories/new-site/node_modules/gifsicle
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ gifsicle pre-build test passed successfully

> jpegtran-bin@3.2.0 postinstall /mnt/c/Users/Jacob/Repositories/new-site/node_modules/jpegtran-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ jpegtran pre-build test passed successfully

> optipng-bin@3.1.4 postinstall /mnt/c/Users/Jacob/Repositories/new-site/node_modules/optipng-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ optipng pre-build test passed successfully

> pngquant-bin@3.1.1 postinstall /mnt/c/Users/Jacob/Repositories/new-site/node_modules/pngquant-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ pngquant pre-build test passed successfully

> node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall /mnt/c/Users/Jacob/Repositories/new-site/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /mnt/c/Users/Jacob/Repositories/new-site/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine

> swiper@4.3.5 postinstall /mnt/c/Users/Jacob/Repositories/new-site/node_modules/swiper
> node -e "console.log('\u001b[35m\u001b[1mLove Swiper? Support Vladimir\'s work by donating or pledging on patreon:\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\n > \u001b[32mhttps://patreon.com/vladimirkharlampidi\u001b[0m\n')"

Love Swiper? Support Vladimir's work by donating or pledging on patreon:
 > https://patreon.com/vladimirkharlampidi

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ mkdirp@0.5.1
added 1969 packages from 803 contributors and audited 24004 packages in 201.431s
found 21 vulnerabilities (4 low, 8 moderate, 9 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Comment: Type `npm -v` and tell us the version you're on

Comment: Duplicate of [Install only one package from package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420564/install-only-one-package-from-package-json). Let's focus there on finding a working solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've figured out why this is happening; apparently if you have a `package-lock.json`, NPM always installs everything in there regardless of the flags you pass. The solution is the `--no-package-lock` flag.

```
npm install --no-package-lock --no-save --quiet stylelint-config-standard stylelint-order stylelint-scss
```

Comment: This [used to work up to NPM 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420564/install-only-one-package-from-package-json/65233880#65233880), but no longer seems to work as of NPM 7.8.0. Even if you delete `package-lock.json` and pass all the arguments you want, `npm install local-iso-dt --no-package-lock --production` will still install everything in `package.json` instead of only that zero-dependencies [local-iso-dt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-iso-dt) module.

Comment: This doesn't work in the newest version of npm v9.5.1 shipped with Nodejs v.18.16.0 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find a native solution via npm, but a possible workaround is to:

```bash
mv package.json package.json.bkp
npm install --no-save eslint stylelint
mv package.json.bkp package.json
```

Since you're doing it in a CI environment, you probably don't care about the last step, but that's an important step if you need to bring your package.json back to its previous state.

Answer (score -2):

Per the npm documentation you can install only `dependencies`, and nothing else.
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

> With the --production flag (or when the NODE_ENV environment variable
>   is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in
>   devDependencies.
>
> NOTE: The --production flag has no particular meaning when adding a
>   dependency to a project.

so, just run `npm install --production`

Comment: That's closer to what I'm trying to do, but I don't need `devDependencies` or `dependencies` installed at all, so it's not quite ideal. I'll see if it works for my purposes.

Comment: Tested, and this seems to *only* install dependencies; if I try to install other modules that aren't in `dependencies` (i.e. `npm i --production stylelint`), they don't actually install. I need to be able to install modules independently of the `package.json`

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question.  Running just `npm install --no-save someDependency` will ONLY install that into node_modules, and not update the package.json.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I thought as well, but doing that it seems to be installing everything in package.json regardless. Will do some more testing on a couple machines to verify.

Comment: Are you sure it's just not all the other dependencies that those you listed rely on?  If you install `foo`, and foo requires `bar baz qux`, you will also see `foo bar baz qux` within node_modules.

Comment: Yea, I'm certain, I just updated the original question with some more detail and example with a very minimal module.

Comment: What version of NPM are you running?  I tested it out with `6.1` and it installs only that dependency (along with whatever it needs), and does NOT install everything from package.json.

Comment: Running NPM 6.4.1, Node 8.12.0. This is the bitname/node:8 Docker container.

Comment: @dvsoukup: [this solution no longer works as of NPM 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786695/npm-install-always-installs-everything-from-package-json#comment118322347_52819886).

Comment: @JacobTheDev: [this solution no longer works as of NPM 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420564/install-only-one-package-from-package-json/65233880#comment118322357_65233880). BTW, the question turns out to be a [duplicate of this 2014 one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420564/install-only-one-package-from-package-json/65233880). Let's close it and focus on that one for a current solution.